# Is there correct way to read and write data of JSON file in Cloud Storage Bucket at Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I struggle to find a documentation GCP to read and write an object of JSON file. But then I found in the [JSON API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api) that every object has JSON format like id, name, metadata, etc. I could use POST, PATCH, GET on it. Then I begin thinking I should have written a JSON data into its metadata. Then it works!

But then what is the purpose of an object inside bucket that contains nothing?
Where I could write custom metadata of its object.

I begin thinking if I was wrong that I write into custom metadata rather than the object/file itself.

Let me know if I can use PATCH on the object/file itself rather than in custom metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Objects in Google Cloud Storage are immutable, which means you cannot patch an object. However, you can change an object using a few steps: read it from Cloud Storage, make the necessary modifications in your application, and then reupload it. Please note that the Storage JSON API is only intended for updating metadata.

Comment: Based on that, so is it okay to add my json data into object's metadata?

Comment: It is not the purpose to store your actual data, but if your JSONs are small enough, it may work for you as a workaround. In another case, if files are very big, it would be better to store them in cloud storage files.

Comment: I see. I will add my json on VALUE metadata as string by decompress using gzip and convert to Base64, maybe like less than 10KB pervalue. So if I have 1000 user, that would be total 10MB, so a less than 100MB.

Do you think 100MB or more are good performance for PATCH or GET method on metadata?

Does that give an impact to performance even I could use query like `fields="KEY"`? Where user's pc didn't read everything.

Comment: Why not use nosql or document oriented database like Firestore where you can update jsons natively? Maybe if you share what is your use case, someone can offer better solution.

Comment: I use Google Cloud Storage because I want try the trial where I could try the feature like to read and write json from Unity like store saved data, write user data, or something that interesting. I have been looking into Firebase, but it's like scarry things, and I want to try first party from Unity Gaming Service that also can read and write json. So I have got confused about Cloud Storage. Maybe I will looking more into  Firestore or Unity Gaming Service.

Comment: Firestore has good free tier 1gb storage, 20k writes, 50k reads and it is fast.